# Android Image from url to image view

Tags: android, android-sdcard, imageurl, memorycache

i am following this tutorial for getting the image from image url.

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-loading-image-from-url-http/

i think he is creating some "**Tempimages**" folder in externalstorage by using the following code

```
 //Find the dir to save cached images
        if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
            cacheDir=new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"TempImages");
        else
            cacheDir=context.getCacheDir();
        if(!cacheDir.exists())
            cacheDir.mkdirs();
```

my question is if the device doen't have an sd card this code will work?

i tried it in emulator with no sd card size it is working fine. can anyone tell me this code will work on Real devices with out SDCard.

and also correct me if understood the code wrongly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**if the device doen't have an sd card this code will work?**

**YES**

`context.getCachedir()` returns /data/data/your.application.package/cache. i.e., The cache directory in Internal Storage.

So it works fine in device too